# Возможно ли продемонстрировать явление полиморфизма в функции main, если базовый класс абстрактный?

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм

Базовый абстрактный класс

```
class Figure
{
public:
    virtual float Square() = 0;
private:
};
```

Класс наследник

```
class Circle :Figure
{
public:    
    Circle(float r) 
    {
        radius = r > 0 ? r : 0;
    }
    virtual float Square()
    {
        return 3.14* radius* radius;
    }

private:
    float radius{};
};
```

Функция main

```
main()
{
    Circle C(3);
    cout << C.Square() << endl;
    Figure *Fig = &C; // здесь ошибка
    cout << Fig->Square;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможность вы должны создавать сами, а для этого нужно  наследовать открыто, а у вас получилось закрытое наследование.

```
 class Circle :Figure {}
```

По умолчанию структуры  наследуют открыто, поэтому выберите один из вариантов:

```
struct Circle : Figure {...  
class Circle : public Figure {...
```

Comment: Ой, так как у меня там было много производных классов, я забыл добавить тип наследования, спасибо

Comment: у вас в коде ошибка есть  при вызове метода  cout << Fig->Square; Скобки забыли в конце